# I've a 4-screen array, how can I make Windows acknowledge them as one giant screen?

Tags: windows, display

I have 4 HP L1710 monitors, mounted to a wall like so:

[image: array photo]

Is there a way I can get Windows to acknowledge all four screens as one giant one? (like so:)

[image: array as one photo]

**Edit: Running Windows 7**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use an NVIDIA graphics card, you can use its built-in utility. The result of it: 4 screens act like one big one and Windows will 'see' it as one monitor.

More information on the nVidia-website: [NVIDIA Mosaic Technology](http://www.nvidia.com/object/nvidia-mosaic-technology.html)

> Featured in NVIDIA® Quadro and NVIDIA® NVS™ graphics card solutions, you can easily span any application across up to 16 high-resolution panels or projectors from a single workstation, without sacrificing performance or power.

I don't know if anything similar is available with other graphics cards, or can be recreated with software.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm using nVidia Quadro cards. This is exactly what I want.